# Phone number validation REGEX

Tags: regex, jquery-validation-engine

I am using the following REGEX for validating phone numbers

```
/^(?!([^-]*-){5})(\+\d+)?\s*(\(\d+\))?[- \d]+$/gi
```

If the input is suppose **+51 (0) 989009890** it is valid. But when the input is **0051 (0) 989009890**. I am new to REGEX so couldnot find a possible solution.

Phone numbers are valid if it is of the following formats.

1. 0xxxxxxxxxxx
2. +xx xxxxxxxxxxx
3. +xxxxxxxxxxxxx
4. +xx (x) xxxxxxxxxx
5. 00xxxxxxxxxx
6. 00xx (x) xxxxxxxxx

here x denotes numbers 0-9. numbers inside () has limit upto 3.

Comment: But when input in `0051*****` ???

Comment: actually what i meant was phone nos can start with 00xxxx but in this case if (xxx) is present then putting 00xxx in front makes it invalid with the given regex

Comment: why `(?!([^-]*-){5})`..what are you trying to achieve here..i mean this can also match `------` or even blank space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to accept `0051 (0) 989009890` as well, the problem is (+\d+)? is meant to handle the bit before the parentheses in the input, but it requires a '+' to be present.  You could change that by making it optional with a '?', like:

```
/^(?!([^-]*-){5})(\+?\d+)?\s*(\(\d+\))?[- \d]+$/gi
```

Or, if '00xxx' should be an alternative to '+xxx' (that is, either a '+' or '00' must be present there), then you could use:

```
/^(?!([^-]*-){5})(\+\d+|00\d+)?\s*(\(\d+\))?[- \d]+$/gi
```

Comment: Why the `/i` considering a number doesn't care about case?

Comment: @h2ooooooo don't forget about upper-case spaces :)

Comment: @Developer why are you using `(?!([^-]*-){5,})`..also the regex would also match `----` or blank spaces

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
^(?!([^-]*-){5,})(\+?\d+)?\s*(\(\d{1,3}\))?\s*[- \d]+$
```